# Memberpress isn't cooperating with WooCommerce

Tags: ajax, plugins, membership

I'm working on a site for a client that has a member subscriptions as well as a small store. We're using [memberpress](http://www.memberpress.com/) to handle subscriptions, and restricting content to certain membership types. For the store we're using woocommerce. The two plugins seem to be conflicting on the checkout page though.

Everything works fine if you are logged in. However if you try to checkout as a guest things get wonky.

In woocommerce's checkout.min.js, there is a function for update_checkout() that has little ajax call. Normally this seems to load the order summary and payment gateway form, however, if you are logged out it ends up loading Memberpress's "URL to direct member to after login:" page in it's entirety within the checkout form page.

So it looks like Memberpress is getting in the way of woocommerce from refreshing data within the checkout form. My question is then, has anyone had experience with disabling Memberpress completely for certain pages of your site?

Or coming at it from another angle is there a way to turn off ajax in the checkout form?

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just solved this. Under memberpress options, we had to uncheck the option to "Keep members out of the WordPress Dashboard". That was it!

I think the woocommerce checkout page was using ajax to call "admin-ajax.php". Memberpress was preventing users from accessing this page so it brought up the login redirect page instead.

We'll keep users out of the dashboard ourselves.

Comment: Please don’t forget to mark your answer as _The Answer_ (the little check mark on the left side).